# Mostrar campos de una base de datos en una tabla

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

```
try {
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        tblPedidos.setModel(modelo);

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String sql = "Select id_plato,pla_descripcion,det_cantidad_plato from plato join detalle_pedido on det_id_plato=id_plato where det_id='"+txtIdPedido+"'";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rs.getMetaData();
        int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

        modelo.addColumn("ID");
        modelo.addColumn("Descripcion");
        modelo.addColumn("Cantidad");


        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];

            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++) {
                filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            modelo.addRow(filas);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

Tengo esta función para insertar los datos que pido en la consulta en una tabla por medio de un textfield que compara un id, cuando le doy al botón buscar me sale la tabla con el nombre de los campos pero no me salen los datos, cual podría ser el error. Ya probé la consulta sql en phpmyadmin y esta correcta, no me sale ningún mensaje de error en consola.

Comment: No estoy 100% seguro, pero me da la impresión que a la consulta le estás pasando el 'txtIdPedido' y no el texto que tiene tu textbox...

Comment: Ay, si vaya error. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Para complementar mi comentario anterior, me parece que se obtiene haciendo algo como `txtIdPedido.getText();` o algo parecido...

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "Select id_plato,pla_descripcion,det_cantidad_plato from plato join detalle_pedido on det_id_plato=id_plato "
                + "where det_id='"+txtIdPedido.getText()+"'";
```

El error estaba en la consulta simplemente tenia txtIdpedido y me tocaba poner txtIdPedido.getText()

Answer (score 0):

En tu consulta estás pasando estás pasando el textbox (txtIdPedido), y deberías pasar el texto que contiene tu textbox, algo como txtIdPedido.getText();

```
String sql = "Select id_plato,pla_descripcion,det_cantidad_plato from plato join detalle_pedido on det_id_plato=id_plato where det_id='"+txtIdPedido.getText()+"'";
```